# How to find url parameters in JavaScript, or jQuery, then apply an event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this url:
/somepage/goes-here/something?image=main_image.jpg&type=shirt

How do I get out the two different attributes to then apply an eventListener to them?

I've tried the following:

```
var originalUrl = window.location.href
var type = originalUrl.search.get("type");
var image = originalUrl.search.get("image");
```

But I don't really think I'm getting the attributes with .search.get. Plus it errors with .search.get("type") is not a function.

I've also tried the following:

```
function getParam(param){
return new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(type);
}
```

I'm honestly not too familiar with URLSearchParams but wouldn't it be similar to above? How would I get both params here?

I also have for jQuery, which I'm not familiar with, the following:

```
$(function(){
$.url.attr('image')
$.url.attr('type')
});
```

This one...no idea. But it fails as it's not bringing in the url.

Comment: Why do you want to add event listeners to strings?

Comment: I don't. I want to add event listeners to buttons that are associated with the parameters. For instance the image has a container around it that I want to be made active. And the type is actually associated with a button. Based on the image and the type being present I want their associations to be made active. Step one, read through and find the parameters being passed. Step two, apply event listeners.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: This is great stuff! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you could construct a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object and grab them as so:

```
var originalUrl = new URL(location.href);
var type = originalUrl.searchParams.get('type');
var image = originalUrl.searchParams.get('image');
```

One thing to note. As of this post it seems that **it's not supported by IE**.

Comment: Using searchParams.get('type') would I get shirt?

Comment: If your url was something like `http://example.com/?type=shirt` I would assume so.